# Django in apache with mod_wsgi confused by os.environ mysite.settings and settings.py

Tags: python, django, apache

Is settings.py the same as mysite.settings from this example here:

http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.X/howto/deployment/modwsgi.html

It seems ambiguous to me if it is the same thing or not, my app has a settings.py in it but it seems like this isn't the same as mysite.settings spoken of in the docs.  I do have my app running with$ python manage.py runserver just fine on centos, and even see apaches test page on the same box so i know apache is running.  Was going through the doc above to try to get apache to server the django app and thats where I got confused as to what it is really asking for...

(also the apache folder didn't exist so I added that and created a django.wsgi with the code below that I think was the right thing to do).

Almost looks like I have to setup a sys.path somewhere?

https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/IntegrationWithDjango.wiki

Answer (score 1):

When you define:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'mysite.settings'
```

Django looks up for `settings.py` file in `mysite` folder. `mysite` folder has to be on your PYTHONPATH. Make sure you set your PYTHONPATH to something like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/work/project:/home/work/project/project:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Okay, really quick question after I follow that tutorial and set it up, I still see the welcome page on apache.  do I have to comment out all lines in that welcome.conf file ?  or something more to get it to actually take off running my app.  I did edit the httpd.conf file with that WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
 which I created in that folder of my site and added the code from the site to. Though, stuck again